# Enable ListView multiselect by dragging

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, multi-select

How do I enable multi-select in a WPF ListView by dragging?

Setting the SelectionMode property to Extended does allow multi-select using Shift and Ctrl, but not by clicking and dragging. Setting the SelectionMode property to Multiple gives a sticky selection which isn't what I want.

Comment: Are you talking like icon selection style?

Answer (score 0):

You could extend `ListView` and `ListViewItem` to implement click and drag multi-select behavior.

A very similar solution was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364029/drag-select-with-listbox/6728555#6728555).

Comment: Does it allow scrolling while dragging?