# Extended Selection in WPF Listbox

Tags: wpf, listbox

we need to customise the Extended Selection in WPF ListBox.
What I need to do is be able to Drag and Select Multiple items(Similar to selecting in excel)

Extended selection in Listbox works fine but for that I have to hold the Shiftkey and drag.

Is there a way I can do the multiple selection just by dragging and not holding the shift key down?

Thanks for looking.

Regards
Saurabh Dighade

Answer (score 0):

This looked promising.  I haven't tested it though.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MultiSelectListView2.aspx

Also, a similar SO post:  [Drag-select with ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364029/drag-select-with-listbox)

Comment: thanks CodeWarrior, there are still some small issues while selections. I will post soon. But thanks for the suggestion.